# Changing cell color in datagridview dynamically from an object list

Tags: c#, datagridview

Can anyone help me how can I add a colored cell in datagridview? The row info comes from an array list. If a Team color is green, I want the cell to be green too. I don't know what index I need to assign.

Here is my code:

```
private void UC_Teams_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TeamList = TeamsOperations.Get(null);
    dg_teams.Rows.Clear();

    foreach (Team t in TeamList)
    {
            for (int i = 0; i < TeamList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (t.Color == "RED")
                {
                    dg_teams.Rows.Add(t.ID, t.name, t.Color, t.productOwner,                 t.scrumMaster);
                    dg_teams.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }

                if (t.Color == "BLUE")
                {
                    dg_teams.Rows.Add(t.ID, t.name, t.Color, t.productOwner, t.scrumMaster);
                    dg_teams.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                }

                if (t.Color == "GREEN")
                {
                    dg_teams.Rows.Add(t.ID, t.name, t.Color, t.productOwner, t.scrumMaster);
                    dg_teams.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }

                if (t.Color == "YELLOW")
                {
                    dg_teams.Rows.Add(t.ID, t.name, t.Color, t.productOwner, t.scrumMaster);
                    dg_teams.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                }

                if (t.Color == "ORANGE")
                {
                    dg_teams.Rows.Add(t.ID, t.name, t.Color, t.productOwner, t.scrumMaster);
                    dg_teams.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was the question really worth posting if you managed to find a solution minutes after posting it on SO?

Comment: I don't understand why i can't post on SO if i have a question. I managed for 30 mins to figure out what was the solution. Is there any problem if I post an answer for my own question?

Comment: No that's not a problem at all. It's definitely recommended. What I was trying to say is that usually it's worth putting bit more effort to solving it before adding it. Consider it a suggestion for future rather than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer . I needed to replace the foreach with a for loop

```
    for (int i = 0; i < TeamList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (TeamList[i].Color == "RED")
            {
                dg_teams.Rows.Add(TeamList[i].ID, TeamList[i].name, TeamList[i].Color, TeamList[i].productOwner, TeamList[i].scrumMaster);
                dg_teams.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            if (TeamList[i].Color == "GREEN")
            {
                dg_teams.Rows.Add(TeamList[i].ID, TeamList[i].name, TeamList[i].Color, TeamList[i].productOwner, TeamList[i].scrumMaster);
                dg_teams.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            if (TeamList[i].Color == "YELLOW")
            {
                dg_teams.Rows.Add(TeamList[i].ID, TeamList[i].name, TeamList[i].Color, TeamList[i].productOwner, TeamList[i].scrumMaster);
                dg_teams.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            if (TeamList[i].Color == "BLUE")
            {
                dg_teams.Rows.Add(TeamList[i].ID, TeamList[i].name, TeamList[i].Color, TeamList[i].productOwner, TeamList[i].scrumMaster);
                dg_teams.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            }
            if (TeamList[i].Color == "ORANGE")
            {
                dg_teams.Rows.Add(TeamList[i].ID, TeamList[i].name, TeamList[i].Color, TeamList[i].productOwner, TeamList[i].scrumMaster);
                dg_teams.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
            }
```